# Begin Try End Try Begin Catch update table end Catch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am in the process of developing a Stored Procedure.

I have a staging table I call `ServiceAssetsBilling`, whereby I am importing the billing information into the relevant tables all the data should go to.

My query is as following:

```
select  @loop = min(idServiceAssetsBilling) from ServiceAssetsBilling where bImported = 0
while   @loop is not null

begin

    begin
        begin transaction
            begin try

                    insert into _smtblContractMatrixPeriodService   (   cCode, cDescription, fAmount, cExternalRef, bInvoiceWithoutConfirmation, bBillInAdvance, cBillingSchedule, dNextDate, iFrequency
                                                                    ,   iJan, iFeb, iMar, iApr, iMay, iJun, iJul, iAug, iSep, iOct, iNov, iDec, iUserId, bDeleted, dtStamp, iAccountId, iContractMatrixID
                                                                    ,   _smtblContractMatrixPeriodService_iBranchID, bIsEscalation, fEscalationPer, fEscalationAmt, fEscFrequency, fEscalationDays
                                                                    ,   iRepeatEscType, bIsPercentage, fOriginalAmount , iProjectId )
                    select
                        cContractNo     cCode
                    ,   cContractDesc   cDescription
                    ,   fAmountExcl     fAmount
                    ,   cOrderNo        cExternalRef
                    ,   0               bInvoiceWithoutConfirmation
                    ,   0               bBillInAdvance
                    ,   case when cBillingSchedule = 'Date Based' then 'DAT' else 'MON' end cBillingSchedule
                    ,   dNextBillDate   dNextDate
                    ,   iRepeatDays     iFrequency
                    ,   iJanuary        iJan
                    ,   iFebruary       iFeb
                    ,   iMarch          iMar
                    ,   iApril          iApr
                    ,   iMay
                    ,   iJune           iJun
                    ,   iJuly           iJul
                    ,   iAugust         iAug
                    ,   iSeptember      iSep
                    ,   iOctober        iOct
                    ,   iNovember       iNov
                    ,   iDecember       iDec
                    ,   1               iUserId
                    ,   0               bDeleted
                    ,   getdate()       dtStamp
                    ,   (select top 1 DCLink from Client where Account = cCustomerCode) iAccountId
                    ,   (select top 1 AutoIdx from _smtblContractMatrix where cCode = cContractNo) iContractMatrixID
                    ,   0               _smtblContractMatrixPeriodService_iBranchID
                    ,   0               bIsEscalation
                    ,   0               fEscalationPer
                    ,   0               fEscalationAmt
                    ,   0               fEscFrequency
                    ,   0               fEscalationDays
                    ,   -1              iRepeatEscType
                    ,   1               bIsPercentage
                    ,   fAmountExcl     fOriginalAmount
                    ,   (select top 1 ProjectLink from Project where ProjectCode = cProject) iProjectId
                    from    ServiceAssetsBilling
                    where   idServiceAssetsBilling = @loop

                    update ServiceAssetsBilling set bImported = 1, cErrorDetails = (case isnull(cErrorDetails,'')   when '' then 'Import Successful!' else  cErrorDetails+' | Import Successful!' end) where idServiceAssetsBilling = @loop

                commit
            end try
            begin catch
                if @@trancount > 0
                    begin

                        set @err = (select error_message())

                        update ServiceAssetsBilling set bImported = 1, bError = 1, cErrorDetails = (case isnull(cErrorDetails,'')   when '' then substring(@err,1,200) else cErrorDetails+' | '+substring(@err,1,200) end)
                        where idServiceAssetsBilling = @loop

                    end
                    rollback transaction;  
            end catch;  

            if @@trancount > 0  
                commit transaction;
    end

    select @loop = min(idServiceAssetsBilling) from ServiceAssetsBilling where idServiceAssetsBilling > @loop
end
```

As you can see, I'm using a Loop.

If the insert fails, **I need to update the same staging table with the error details, but it does not update.**

When I add :

```
SELECT   
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
```

it shows me the errors, **but I need to update this error/s into the `cErrorDetails` Column of the staging table**.

I've googled as much as I can to get the answer, but I'm stuck.

Please advise what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

In the below script (cut out from the question):

```
        begin catch
            if @@trancount > 0
                begin

                    set @err = (select error_message())

                    update ServiceAssetsBilling set bImported = 1, bError = 1, cErrorDetails = (case isnull(cErrorDetails,'')   when '' then substring(@err,1,200) else cErrorDetails+' | '+substring(@err,1,200) end)
                    where idServiceAssetsBilling = @loop

                end
                rollback transaction;  
        end catch;
```

I'm rolling back the transaction, causing it not to update the staging table.

After changing it to look like this:

```
        begin catch
            if @@trancount > 0
                begin
                rollback transaction; 

                    set @err = (select error_message())

                    update ServiceAssetsBilling set bImported = 1, bError = 1, cErrorDetails = (case isnull(cErrorDetails,'')   when '' then substring(@err,1,200) else cErrorDetails+' | '+substring(@err,1,200) end)
                    where idServiceAssetsBilling = @loop

                end 
        end catch;
```

It worked!